# Species atlas (how to automate to create on page for each species with QGIS)

Tags: qgis, map-book

With the use of QGIS, I would like to create an Atlas for a batch of species, with:

- a background with the country (from a vector layer or from the OpenLayers plugin).
- a vector layer (polygon) to show the watershed or administrative boundaries
- a vector layer (polygon) with the distribution for each species (all the species are on the same file) from IUCN data.
- a vector layer (point) with all the GBIF occurrences (all the species are on the same file)

All the maps will have the same footprint (the country) and need to have the legend, a title with the name of the specie and some other elements (north arrow, company logo, etc.). For the export format, it can be as a picture or as a PDF file.
I already look at the documentation of the Atlas plugin (now integrate by default on QGIS 2), but this is to made dynamic atlas, for my need, the footprint is all the time the country coverage.

So my questions are:

- Is there any plugin, any extension or other which can do it easily?
- Few month ago, I already asked advice for a similar example ([Generating large number of maps using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52659/how-do-i-generate-a-large-number-of-maps)), but it was for polygon and not point, and furthermore, there were nothing for the render (no legend, no title, no logo, etc.). So how is it possible for this kind of script to take consideration of the map composer?
- Optionally, I would like to incorporate to each map, a list of the watershed or administrative area list where the species occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I finish to finding a great part (I would like to add now a table with the waterbassin list where I have got occurrences) of solution to solve my problem:

[Here an example](http://www.portailsig.org/content/qgis-20-script-pour-exporter-un-atlas-par-valeur-unique#) (in french) of a script which permit to extract unique value and made a map using the map composer which quite nice because we can a great liberty.

[Through this discussion](http://www.forumsig.org/showthread.php/37685-G%C3%A9n%C3%A9rer-une-s%C3%A9rie-d-exports-selon-la-valeur-d-un-champ/page2) (in french), some more details to add other layers (which have the same unique value).