# Is it possible to include the Map composer in Sextante for QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis-2, print-composer, qgis-processing

I would like to solve a problem ([Species atlas (how to automate to create on page for each species with QGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76626/species-atlas-how-to-automate-to-create-on-page-for-each-species-with-qgis)).
To solve it by an other way, I would like to know if it is possible to make a sextante process, and at the end, call, or use the map composer, directly into the Models Builder?
If yes, how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know: **No** 
The Map composer is mainly build to be a user friendly click-and-point tool and it requires some sort of python script to automatically generate a map within the Processing modeller. 
So you have 2 ways to proceed:

- Ether write yourself a custom python script to be used in the modeller. For this you just have to alter the provided python-code from your other [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52659/how-do-i-generate-a-large-number-of-maps).
- In my opinion more straight forward is to write a simple [R](http://cran.r-project.org/) script that generates the maps for you. See an example how to port r-script to QGIS processing on [my blog](http://conservationecology.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/port-your-r-scripts-to-qgis-using-sextante/).
  You could for instance write sth. like this (quick and dirty):

Code:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
r <- raster("raster path")
pol <- readOgr("polygon dir","polgygon name")


png("where to save.png")
plot(r)
plot(pol,add=T)
dev.off()
```